# REDIS cannot query for specific criteria

Tags: c, linux, redis

I to have store the below values:

```
subId 10 Recipient 999999999999 file /home/sach/ status 1.
```

I used REDIS to store these values. Ex:

```
HMSET 1 subId 10 Recipient 999999999999 file /home/sach/ status 1
```

But with REDIS I can't query for a specific criteria as REDIS can be queried only with the key fields. For example I need query only for the `Recipient 988888888888`, but REDIS lacks this kind of querying.

Is there any other simple Databases except Mongo and Mysql where I can store these type of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Redis, you just have to manually handle the secondary indexes, by maintaining set or hash objects.

When you add an object, pipeline the following queries:

```
HMSET 1 subId 10 Recipient 999999999999 file /home/sach/ status 1
SADD subId:10 1
SADD Recipient:999999999999 1
SADD file:/home/sach/ 1
SADD status:1 1
```

If you need to query the items for a given subId and recipient:

```
SINTER subId:10 Recipient:999999999999
```

Then you just need an extra roundtrip to fetch the data corresponding to the returned id.

Actually, many distributed NoSQL stores, except the ones which are pure key/value (memcached for instance), can handle secondary indexes (manually or automatically): Couchbase, CouchDB, Cassandra, Riak, Neo4j, OrientDB, Hyperdex, ArrangoDB, etc ...